# "Select to Copy and Middle Click to Paste" in Windows

Tags: windows, autohotkey, productivity

Is there any application to mimic the "Select to Copy and Middle Click to Paste" behaviour in Windows? I was hoping to find an AutoHotkey script for this, but I couldn't. Maybe someone here could quickly hack one for this :).

Comment: I know it's kind of specific, but GVIM for Windows actually inserts the content of the normal clipboard when middle-clicked. I would really like more optional productivity features in Windows like the one you're asking for.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, there's the [True X-Mouse Gizmo](http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/nt/TXMouse/), if that works in your Windows version (it's a bit dated).

Comment: Here I can use the expression it worked like charm!

Comment: It is unbelievable how this works fine after so many years

Comment: Works under Win 10, it uses the main clipboard, but : you need to select all the way, a double-click on a word to select it won't copy it ; it kills middle-click to open in a new tab ; it pastes in the textbox which has the focus, not the one under your cursor (you need an extra click to give focus).

Comment: double and triple click highlighting don't seem to work

Answer (score 30):

If you're looking for an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script, [**this one**](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic47816.html) should probably do!

> Here's an implementation for copy on
>   select. You can simply select some
>   text and it is copied immediately
>   without having to press ctrl+c.
>
> Conveinent middle button paste is also
>   provided, but with a twist.
>   Middlebutton is useful in browsers, so
>   there is a short time (configurable)
>   while you can paste with the middle
>   button after copy, before original
>   middleclick functionality is restored.
>
> Also, if you click with the right
>   button it cancels middlebutton paste.
>
> Since after selection you usually
>   click with the left button to the
>   place where you want to paste, so that
>   you put the focus there, it is done
>   automatically when using middlebutton
>   pasting.
>
> clipx integration is also added to
>   Ctrl+middlebutton.
>
> I've been using the script for a few
>   days and it's quite convenient.
>   Sometimes the copy tooltip appears
>   unwantedly when something is dragged,
>   but it doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: This works great, especially if you only want copy on select. True X-Mouse Gizmo will make the middle click useless which is pretty annoying if you used to open new tab with middle click.

Comment: the script has been updated later on: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/post-290035.html&sid=ed5a79403898919c2ef411b592fe14ac#290035

Comment: Autohotkey is an awesome tool. Thanks for suggesting this.

Comment: However good the mouse dragging idea sounds, I prefer just double-clicking the word to copy it. The reason I started looking for this sort of 'highlight-copy-paste' solution is that addons and extensions make my browser slower. So, I decided to find a desktop app. The Autocopy 2 on Firefox works exactly as I like:
1) double click the word and it gets automatically copied.
2) ctrl+v OR  RMouse button + Paste.
The solution with Autohotkey and the script seems good, however after that simple functionality in Firefox I understood what simple and easy means.
Maybe, somebody could rewrite it?

Answer (score 13):

Check out [AutoClipX](https://autoclipx.informer.com/download/).

> AutoClipX is a highly configurable program that automatically copies selected objects to the Windows clipboard like text, files and folders. Quickly paste what you have copied by clicking a mouse button! AutoClipX runs quietly in the system tray while you work as usual.

Comment: It helps to explain why this is a solution, rather than just linking to one.

Comment: Updated URL: https://autoclipx.informer.com/download/

Comment: This works excellently - except you need to get the old freeware version 2.1.2.0 ( see https://filehippo.com/download_autoclipx/ newer ones are paywalled to an expired domain, so useless now) and create the missing folder it complains about when you install, and change the permissions on that folder to allow the program to write into it - then it works perfectly on windows 10+

Answer (score 2):

Shallow copy on selection and shallow paste on middle click in Windows 11 (AutoHotkey script):

```
cos_mousedrag_treshold := 20 ; pixels
cos_copied_text := ""

#IfWinNotActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass

~lButton::
  MouseGetPos, cos_mousedrag_x, cos_mousedrag_y
  keywait lbutton
  mousegetpos, cos_mousedrag_x2, cos_mousedrag_y2
  if (abs(cos_mousedrag_x2 - cos_mousedrag_x) > cos_mousedrag_treshold
    or abs(cos_mousedrag_y2 - cos_mousedrag_y) > cos_mousedrag_treshold)
  {
    wingetclass cos_class, A
    if (cos_class == "Emacs")
      sendinput !w
    else {
      previous_clipboard := clipboard
      sendinput ^c
      sleep 50 ; wait for copied text to be stored in clipboard
      cos_copied_text := clipboard
      clipboard := previous_clipboard
    }
  }
  return

~mbutton::
  WinGetClass cos_class, A
  if (cos_class == "Emacs")
    SendInput ^y
  else {
    previous_clipboard := clipboard
    clipboard := cos_copied_text ; copy stored text to clipboard
    SendInput ^v
    sleep 50 ; I'm not sure if this is necessary
    clipboard := previous_clipboard
  }
  return

#IfWinNotActive

;; clipx
^mbutton::
  sendinput ^+{insert}
  return
```

This is a modified version of [@Snark](https://superuser.com/users/10131/snark)'s answer, which in turn is taken from [an anonymous post](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/44064-copy-on-select-implementation/#entry274436).

To use this AutoHotkey script, you need to have AutoHotkey installed on your computer. Once you've installed AutoHotkey, save this script as a .ahk file and then double-click the file to run it. The script will run in the background, you can see its icon on the right side of the taskbar.

Comment: Note that this script doesn't work with the latest AutoHotKey v2, so you need to install v1.1 or lower.

Comment: potentially might not work in Visual Studio Code with the vim editor - because ^c does not copy, and "sendinput ^c" looks like it needs that ?  Maybe AHK has some other way to do a copy besides that?

Answer (score -3):

```
SetWinDelay,2
CoordMode,Mouse
return

~MButton::
sleep 100
    Send, ^v
return
~LButton:: 

MouseGetPos x0, y0
   Loop
   {
     Sleep 20
     GetKeyState keystate, LButton
     IfEqual keystate, U, {
       MouseGetPos x, y
       break
     }
   }
   if (x-x0 > 5 or x-x0 < -5 or y-y0 > 5 or y-y0 < -5)
   {                             
      Send ^c
   }


 if (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < DllCall("GetDoubleClickTime"))            
      Send ^c

 if (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < DllCall("GetDoubleClickTime"))
 doubleclick := true

return

#If doubleclick
  ~LButton::
  doubleclick := false
  if (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < DllCall("GetDoubleClickTime"))
  {
      Send, ^c
  }
  return
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.