# Clipboard feature in Windows

Tags: windows-xp, x-windows, clipboard, selection

In Opensuse 11.0 Linux we can select any piece of text anywhere(browser, emacs..) and its in the clipboard and then we can paste it with the middle mouse click. How can i get similar functionality in Windows Xp?

Comment: you're looking for "x-windows"-style mouse selection behavior.  are you trying to get both auto-copy-on-selection *and* paste-on-middle-mouse-click?

Comment: yep...thats exactly correct

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/84550/select-to-copy-and-middle-click-to-paste-in-windows

Comment: there's a ahk in here : http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic47816.html  , but it doesn't retain the paste buffer after a single paste of the last copied material

Answer (score 1):

found a nice tool: [txmouse](http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/nt/TXMouse/)

Comment: does it work in windows 7?

Comment: yes it does, but unfortunately it also does implement non-optional mouse cursor focusing. (also, you should check your answer as accepted)