# Is there a way to use the X-Window select - middle-click-to-paste behaviour on Windows?

Tags: windows, mouse, clipboard

On Linux, the last text selected can be pasted via a middle click, making copy-pasting faster for one thing, and additionally providing a second clipboard. Is there a way to add this feature to Windows 7?

[True X-Mouse](http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/nt/TXMouse/) seems to provide this, but [it also adds the mouse-over focusing](http://lifehacker.com/294701/copy-and-paste-quicker-using-your-mouse-with-true-x+mouse-gizmo) which I'd like to *not* have, and there seems to be no setting to switch that off, so are there alternatives?

Comment: almost duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/133211/clipboard-feature-in-windows but I explicitly do _not_ want that mouse-over focusing behaviour

Answer (score 2):

You could try an AHK Script for this

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/post-127875.html&sid=a161df5a1a57d47f946ed4e43ee10157#127875

Comment: that thread shows only half the work, but you made me find [this SU answer](http://superuser.com/questions/84550/select-to-copy-and-middle-click-to-paste-in-windows/84576#84576) linking to [another thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/post-290035.html&sid=ed5a79403898919c2ef411b592fe14ac#290035) that has a full script

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy with a Microsoft mouse, as the IntelliPoint software lets you define just about any common function to any of the mouse buttons.  I would be surprised if the Logitech mouse software did not have something similar as well.

Comment: but does it copy a selected text to a buffer simply when the left mouse button is released? I'm no admin on this machine and no special drivers are installed so I can't check this